# Using getx obx and GetX state management inside getx dialog flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using Get dialog in my app and I want to use GetX state management inside my dialog widget for example I have checkbox inside my dialog and I want to update it's state with GetX however when I use the `GetX<AppController>()` inside my get dialog I ran into following error

> You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be
> updated.
> If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
> or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
> (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
> If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
> Here is the sample code:

```
Get.dialog(
      Dialog(
        child: Flexible(
            child: GetX<AppController>(
              init: appController,
              builder: (val){
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("Power off computer"),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  value: appController.powerOffRaspberry,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    appController.powerOffRaspberry = !appController.powerOffRaspberry;
                  },
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
                );
              },
            )
        ),
      ),

    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `appController.powerOffRaspberry` observable:

```
final powerOffRaspberry = false.obs;
```

Update `CheckboxListTile` as:

```
CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text("Power off computer"),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              value: appController.powerOffRaspberry.value,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                appController.powerOffRaspberry.value = !appController.powerOffRaspberry.value;
              },
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
            )
```